# Is it possible to test css property of some element, defined in external css file, using Selenium Webdriver and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, acceptance-testing

How can I test css properties of any web-page element, which is defined in external css file. If I had, for example:

```
<div id="some-div" style="opasity: 10;"></div>
```

I could just take the value of `style` attribute, **BUT** I have all css properties defined in external ccs files. How can I test such elements and their properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use IWebElement.GetCssValue**

There is a method for getting the computed css style. I believe in c# it is the [IWebElement.GetCssValue](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetCssValue.htm) method.

Note that in the documentation for this method in ruby and java says the following. I assume it applies to c# even though it is not mentioned.

> Note that shorthand CSS properties (e.g. background, font, border,
>   border-top, margin, margin-top, padding, padding-top, list-style,
>   outline, pause, cue) are not returned, in accordance with the [DOM
>   CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) - you should directly access the longhand
>   properties (e.g. background-color) to access the desired values.

**Example (ruby)**

Since I have only done selenium-webdriver in ruby, I can only give a ruby example (idea is the same though the api is slightly different):

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://yourpage.com"

element = driver.find_element(:id, 'id')
puts element.css_value('color')
```