# How To Get Color of WebElement From Complicated css case using Webdriver?

Tags: java, css, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to check if color of some page is changing right when i click on button that should change the color of element inside that page, now what i need is to get value of rgb where is written rgb(183,168,168);, how can i access exactly this value in my case?

```
`.matrix-var1 .dmNav li a {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset, 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   padding: 5px 0px;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
   100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(183, 168, 168);`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to test css property of some element, defined in external css file, using Selenium Webdriver and C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069909/is-it-possible-to-test-css-property-of-some-element-defined-in-external-css-fil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so using the `getCssValue()` method.

So something like `driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getCssValue("background-color");`